# can I get a jdbc datasource from jpa in spring application context?

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc, initialization

as you know, in spring applicationContext we can define entityManagerFactory bean from persistence.xml  just like:

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />   
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

now if I want initialize the database as follow:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="myDataSource" enabled="true">
   <jdbc:script location="classpath*:com/myapp/data*.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

should I must config another data source bean for it? or I can ref to emf defined above ,or can ref to persistence.xml ?

Comment: @skaffman: It is from the spring reference: 12.9.1 Initializing a database instance using Spring XML

"If you want to initialize a database and you can provide a reference to a DataSource bean, use the initialize-datasource tag in the spring-jdbc namespace:"

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!-- use jndi lookup, or define it by your selfe -->
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource" />  

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <!-- this is important to connect JPA and JdbcTemplate transaction control -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- jdbc templates that are equals for all databases -->
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" id="jdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate" id="simpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```